# No Wifi Adapter Found Ubuntu 20.04 but there's a wifi icon at the top

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, 20.04, adapter

I was using ubuntu 20.04 and suddenly wifi stops working i have a wifi icon above but when i use select network it gives no networks and when i opened wifi settings i got `No Wifi Adapter Found` i tried a lot of solutions online but nothing seems working.

output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list`

```
Plus Bluetooth [8086:3166] (rev 99)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 3165 Plus Bluetooth [8086:4210]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: wl, iwlwifi
0: tpacpi_bluetooth_sw: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: First step is to remove the wl driver, `sudo apt remove bcmwl-kernel-source` then disable power management with `sudo sed -i 's/wifi.powersave = 3/wifi.powersave = 2/' /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf` then reboot

Comment: My problem is i got no WIFI adapter found.

Comment: @Jeremy31 i tried your solution and reboot, still has the same no wifi adapter found but the icon appears above.